# Move method from the view in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In the view I want to display the total balance. I do it that way.

controller:

```
def index
  @invoices = Invoice.balance
end
```

views:

```
 .pull-right
  strong The total balance:
  = @invoices.map(&:balance).sum
```

I understand that it's wrong.

How can I move this method in the model?

```
def total_balance
  Invoice.all.map(&:balance).sum
end
```

If you do so, then how to use in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a class method:

```
def self.total_balance
  sum(:balance)
end
```

And then simply call it in your view on the invoices collection:

```
= @invoices.total_balance
```